# ¿Cómo evitar registros duplicados en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli

Este bloque de código solo me esta registrando pero no se ¿cómo evitar que me guarde registros que ya existen?

```
<?php 

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");


    $id_Funcionario = $_POST["id_Funcionario"];
    $primer_Nombre = $_POST["primer_Nombre"];
    $segundo_Nombre = $_POST["segundo_Nombre"];
    $primer_Apellido = $_POST["primer_Apellido"];
    $segundo_Apellido = $_POST["segundo_Apellido"];
    $cargo_Funcionario = $_POST["cargo_Funcionario"];
    $telefono_Funcionario = $_POST["telefono_Funcionario"];
    $edad_Funcionario = $_POST["edad_Funcionario"];
    $sexo_Funcionario = $_POST["sexo_Funcionario"];


$insertar = "INSERT INTO usuario (id_Funcionario, primer_Nombre,
segundo_Nombre, primer_Apellido, segundo_Apellido, cargo_Funcionario,
telefono_Funcionario, edad_Funcionario, sexo_Funcionario) VALUES(
'".$id_Funcionario."','".$primer_Nombre."','".$segundo_Nombre."',
'".$primer_Apellido."','".$segundo_Apellido."','".$cargo_Funcionario."',
'".$telefono_Funcionario."','".$edad_Funcionario."','".$sexo_Funcionario."')";


    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);
    if (!$resultado) {

            echo '<script>
                    alert("El funcionario NO fue registrado");
             </script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script>
                    alert("El funcionario fue registrado");
             </script>';
    }

?>
```

esta es mi tabla

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Consultas</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
       <h1>Formulario Registro</h1>
       <form action="registrar.php" method="post" class="form-register">
        <h2 class="form__titulo">Registrar funcionario</h2>
        <div class="contenedor-inputs"></div>
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="id_Funcionario" placeholder="Cedula" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="primer_Nombre" placeholder="Primer Nombre" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="segundo_Nombre" placeholder="Segundo Nombre" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="primer_Apellido" placeholder="Primer Apellido" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="segundo_Apellido" placeholder="Segundo Apellido" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="cargo_Funcionario" placeholder="Cargo Funcionario" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="telefono_Funcionario" placeholder="Telefono Funcionario" class="input-100">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="edad_Funcionario" placeholder="Edad Funcionario">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="sexo_Funcionario" placeholder="Sexo">
        <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn-enviar">
        <input type="button" value="Volver de donde viniste!" onclick="history.back(-1)" /> 
        </center>
      </form>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tendrás que dar más información. ¿Tiene tu tabla PK? Pon más código y explica más de tu arquitectura.

Comment: si claro tengo el formulario de registro sino, pero es el codigo que me esta registrando los datos que ingreso pero quiero evitar que existan registros duplicados

Comment: bueno primero y antes que nada para evitar registros duplicados tienes que tener un identificador único en la base de datos algo que no se va a repetir jamas de un usuario o persona, muchos usan el correo electrónico, pero igual puedes usar la CURP si estas en México. Si estas en otro país identifica cual es el id de una persona, antes de agregar el usuario a la base de datos harás una consulta validando si existe ya un correo o curp en la db, si ya existe entonces le mandas una alerta q ya existe y no guardas nada y en otro caso que no existe procedes a guardarlo. Espero te sirva.

Comment: asi lo estado intentando de hacer pero no me funciona

Comment: ¿Cómo es la tabla donde se guardan los datos? ¿Cuál es su clave primaria? ¿Cómo insertas los datos?

Comment: Pon la definición de tu tabla

Comment: Muestra tu código, porque concuerdo con Christopher Flores

Comment: la clave primaria es id_Funcionario los datos ya se estan insertando en el primer bloque de codigo

Comment: si sirvio pero Ahora ya no me registra los que no existen

Comment: usa un print_r para ver que resultado te esta arrojando la variable $exist

Comment: Cuando trabajas con php es más complicado que este tipo de lógicas las hagas desde este lugar. No sé si sea el caso tuyo, pero si llevas base de datos podés hacer la lógica dentro de un procedimiento almacenado. Este sería el que realice la verificación si los datos ya existen en otra tupla. Y lo único que quedaría por hacer desde php sería ejecutar el procedimiento con tus datos como parámetros de entrada. También mencionar que es conveniente que este tipo de procesos los realice el gestor de base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Es importante saber si tu clave primaria, o identificador de usuario en este caso, es numérico y tiene configurada la opción de auto incrementarse con cada nuevo registro.

Si este fuera el caso, debes hacer la consulta previa como te indicó Christopher, para saber si aquel ID ya existe en la tabla.

Si por el contrario, tu identificador no es autonumérico, tienes dos caminos para optar:

A) Hacer lo mismo que ya te dijo Christopher, de averiguar previo si el ID ya existe en la tabla con una consulta SELECT simple.

B) No hacer la consulta previa, pero en su lugar, capturar el Error que te arrojará la base de datos, respecto a que estás intentando ingresar un usuario que ya existe. Este error se conoce por lo general como "intentar insertar una clave duplicada" (duplicated key). Busca en la documentación de Mysql los códigos de error de servidor, y obtén el número de error exacto para esta situación. Luego, en tu código, con mysqli_errno() o función afín obtienes el código de error, y si es el que ya sabes, le avisas al usuario que está usando la página que el usuario ya existe.

***Con la opción B) no necesitas consultar si el registro existe previamente.

En tu código, esta captura iría aquí:

```
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);
    if (!$resultado) {

       $error_id_duplicado = XXXX; // tú reemplaza las X con el código que corresponde, investígalo en https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html
       if (mysqli_errno($conexion) == $error_id_duplicado)
       {
            echo '<script>
                    alert("El funcionario Ya Existe.");
             </script>';
       }
       else
       {
            echo '<script>
                    alert("El funcionario NO fue registrado");
             </script>';
       }
    }else{
        echo '<script>
                    alert("El funcionario fue registrado");
             </script>';
    }
```

Comment: la clave primaria es id_Funcionario es de tipo numerico

Comment: Ok, pero además de eso, fíjate si tiene el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT definido.

Comment: como hago para saber eso?

Comment: Si tienes acceso a un administrador de base de datos, como phpmyadmin, puedes ver eso en la estructura de la tabla ¿tienes acceso a algún administrador de mysql donde puedas ver las tablas y sus datos directo? Si no tienes, lo puedes averiguar también por consulta (`SHOW COLUMNS FROM tu_tabla`).

Comment: no tiene este atributo

Comment: Ah, entonces, estás listo, puedes hacer como te dijo Chris, o bien la otra opción que te mencioné: B) Capturar el error. Editaré mi respuesta para indicarte en qué parte de tu código debe ir esta captura.

Comment: esta bien gracias