# como valido que no existan registros duplicados?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito evitar la duplicidad de registros en mi base de datos, especificamente en mi tabla `usuario` tomando en cuenta el campo `id_Funcionario` perteneciente a la tabla.

Este es el formulario:

registro.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Consultas</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
       <h1>Formulario Registro</h1>
       <form action="registrar.php" method="post" class="form-register">
        <h2 class="form__titulo">Registrar funcionario</h2>
        <div class="contenedor-inputs"></div>
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="id_Funcionario" placeholder="Cedula" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="primer_Nombre" placeholder="Primer Nombre" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="segundo_Nombre" placeholder="Segundo Nombre" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="primer_Apellido" placeholder="Primer Apellido" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="segundo_Apellido" placeholder="Segundo Apellido" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="cargo_Funcionario" placeholder="Cargo Funcionario" class="input-48">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="telefono_Funcionario" placeholder="Telefono Funcionario" class="input-100">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="edad_Funcionario" placeholder="Edad Funcionario">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="sexo_Funcionario" placeholder="Sexo"></br>
        <br><input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn-enviar">
        <input type="button" value="Volver!" onclick="history.back(-1)" style="margin-left: 3%" /></br> 
        </center>
      </form>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Y aquí esta la inserción en la base de datos:

registrar.php

```
<?php 

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");

$id_Funcionario = $_POST["id_Funcionario"];
$primer_Nombre = $_POST["primer_Nombre"];
$segundo_Nombre = $_POST["segundo_Nombre"];
$primer_Apellido = $_POST["primer_Apellido"];
$segundo_Apellido = $_POST["segundo_Apellido"];
$cargo_Funcionario = $_POST["cargo_Funcionario"];
$telefono_Funcionario = $_POST["telefono_Funcionario"];
$edad_Funcionario = $_POST["edad_Funcionario"];
$sexo_Funcionario = $_POST["sexo_Funcionario"];


$insertar = "INSERT INTO usuario (id_Funcionario, primer_Nombre, segundo_Nombre, primer_Apellido, segundo_Apellido, cargo_Funcionario, telefono_Funcionario, edad_Funcionario, sexo_Funcionario) VALUES( '".$id_Funcionario."',                 '".$primer_Nombre."','".$segundo_Nombre."','".$primer_Apellido."','".$segundo_Apellido."','".$cargo_Funcionario."',
'".$telefono_Funcionario."','".$edad_Funcionario."','".$sexo_Funcionario."')";


$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);
if (!$resultado) {

    header("location:MostrarRegistros.php");

}else{
    echo '<script>
    alert("El funcionario fue registrado");
    </script>';

}


?>
```

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta, creo que algunas partes no se muestran correctamente, y otras quedan entre código y texto normal, lo cual impide ver con claridad tu pregunta.

Comment: listo amigo ya lo edite

Comment: Uhm, este código ya lo había visto, y no sé, pero siento que ya había respondido aquella vez XD... Las opciones que di en su momento era (1) realizar una consulta previo a insertar, para averiguar si el `$id_funcionario` existe en la BD, y si lo encuentra, avise y no deje continuar la inserción; y (2) permitir que pase la inserción, y al momento de fallar, capturar el error, que te indicará que el registro ya existe. Según el motor de base de datos, existen códigos propios para este error, que generalmente será descrito como `duplicated key`.

Comment: como escribo esto dentro mi codigo?

Comment: Acá encontré tu pregunta, junto a mi respuesta: [¿Cómo evitar registros duplicados en mi base de datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/146901/78037) (tal vez te borren una de las preguntas, ya que dicen casi lo mismo...)

Comment: lo voy a intentar de nuevo pero no me funciono aquella vez

Comment: no logro realizar la validacion

Answer (score 2):

haz que tu id_Funcionario sea Primary Key  en tu base de datos  y la propia base de datos  no te permitira que haya dos registros con el mismo  id_Funcionario

para hacer que tu columna sea llave primaria  has de ejecutar algo parecido a esto en tu base de datos

```
ALTER TABLE base_de_datos.tabla ADD PRIMARY KEY (columna);//columna = id_Funcionario
```